# Is random UUID Generation in Oracle timebased?

Tags: oracle

I need to generate UUID which takes into consideration the timestamp too. So that it does not get duplicated anytime in future

Comment: Do you know what "UUID" means?

Comment: https://docs.oracle.com/en/database/oracle/oracle-database/18/sqlrf/SYS_GUID.html#GUID-761E36B4-32DA-497D-8829-3D4653381F9B

Comment: @ruakh I understand what UUID is. Let me elaborate my concern. The scene here is we have an existing java code which generates UUID using fasterxml.uuid.generators which takes into consideration timestamp too. Now i need to migrate older data into the table and generate UUID in Oracle. So i am concerned since the underlying algorithms are different in both cases, would there be any overlap in any UUID's generated using oracle with those getting generated in Java in future.

Comment: A UUID is always unique (well, not exactly "unique", but collisions are **extremely** unlikely), regardless which algorithm you use - as long as you are using a proper algorithm. You can assume that Java's `java.util.UUID.randomUUID()` and Oracles `sys_guid()` a properly implemented regarding that.

Comment: @AmitaRawat - you could generate the UUID through Java [within the database](https://docs.oracle.com/en/database/oracle/oracle-database/12.2/jjdev/invoking-Java-methods.html#GUID-21F89FA2-D947-42C1-B16A-6722A219EBDA)?

Comment: @a_horse_with_no_name Thanks. But i am still worried as i see a lot of posts on oracle Guid collision (https://sqlfascination.com/2012/01/22/oracle-duplicate-guid-values-being-returned-from-sys_guid-when-run-in-parallel/) . Incorporating timestamp would have avoided it.

Comment: @AlexPoole Yes there is a provision to call java functions from oracle. That is going to be the last option if i do not get any algorithm in oracle which takes into consideration the timestamp for UUID.

Comment: "*When run on an AIX box ... which is indicating that this is a platform specific bug*" Are you using AIX?

Comment: @AmitaRawat: In the post that you link to, I see no evidence that including the timestamp would have prevented the issue, and in fact, no evidence that Oracle *doesn't* include the timestamp. The whole point of that post is that on that system, GUIDs generated at the *same* time can end up the same. (Which, wow, that's really bad!)